# TypeError: 'exceptions.NameError' object is not callable

Tags: python, subprocess

I am getting `TypeError: 'exceptions.NameError' object is not callable`

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
command = 'sudo /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop fs -put '+hadoopInputFile+ ' /input'
rtVal  = subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
```

Comment: I am very new to python please help TypeError: 'exceptions.NameError' object is not callable,

Comment: Is there any other code here that could be contributing?

Comment: @MohanaDeepthi Could you include the part of your code where hapoopInputFile is initialised?

Comment: upld_folder = "/home/ubuntu/tempfiles/"
        file = request.files['file[]']
        txt = file.read()
        tmpfile =  upld_folder+ str(file.filename)
        ec2_file=open(tmpfile,'wb')
        ec2_file.write(txt)
        hadoopInputFile=upld_folder+str(file.filename)